# Terrform dyamic block with for_each not working with empty list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to extend a module that wraps AWS Secrets Manager. Currently it doesn't support replication and I'm trying to add it. I'm using terraform 0.14.

Here's the variable I've added:

```
variable "replica_regions" {
  type        = list(string)
  description = "A List of Regions"
  default     = []
}
```

And here's what I've added inside the "aws_secretsmanager_secret" resource:

```
  dynamic "replica" {
    for_each = var.replica_regions
    content {
      region = replica.value
    }
  }
```

This appears to work in that when I add regions it starts to replicate the secret to those regions. And when I remove regions from the list it stops replicating them there. The only issue is when I try to go from 1 region to zero regions, it doesn't seem to do anything and the secret is still be replicated. This happens when I remove `replica_regions` from the invocation and when I explicitly set it to `[]`.

Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: And if you set the default value to `[""]`?

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example of your `aws_secretsmanager_secret`  which works and which does not?

Comment: @MarkoE If I do that I get: `Error: error adding Secrets Manager Secret replica: InvalidParameterException: Invalid replica region.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug of `terraform-provider-aws`. If the bug is fixed, it is expected that secret replication will be deleted when variable is in `[]` state.

[This issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23316) should be resolved.

Comment: It does seem like this is a good idea, unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. When I add the `toset` the replica still remains when `var.replica_regions` is `[]`

Comment: @IgniFerroque I figured this out again. And I've edited the answer. We have to wait until the aws terraform provider is fixed.